# Angular APP_BASE_HREF does not match Response URL

Tags: angular, dotnetnuke, angular2-routing, angular2-http

> Angular 2.4.9

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/dnn/desktopmodules/dnnangular2'}]
```

When making a call to an API, within the context of `http.umd.js`:

`req.url` = api/products/products.json

`getResponseURL(_xhr) || req.url` = _http://localhost/dnn/desktopmodules/**product**/api/products/products.json

It is mangling the url by inserting **product**. Unfortunately the execution of XHR is a patched version of `window.XMLHttpRequest` so I cannot see why the response url no longer matches `APP_BASE_HREF`. Furthermore, the API call works with the first route, but not the parameterized route.

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent },
        {
            path: 'product/:id',
            canActivate: [ProductDetailGuard],
            component: ProductDetailComponent
        }
    ])
```

I am suspicious that **product** is what is getting inserted into the response URL and my parameterized route definition has `'product/:id'`. I have done a cursory search through `router.umd.js` and can see nothing that may modify `APP_BASE_HREF`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The things are mixed up. What is response url that does not match? APP_BASE_HREF affects routing. Not Http requests. While `api/products/products.json` url suggests that it is requested with http.get.

Comment: @estus The only value that exists in the HTTP module at the time of the request is `api/products/products.json`. When `zone.js` makes a call to `sendNative`which is a patched implementation of `window.XMLHttpRequest` i assume the patched native code is what appending `http://localhost/dnn/desktopmodules/product/`. Where does it get this value from? I thought it would be `APP_BASE_HREF`.

Comment: No, it isn't APP_BASE_HREF. The manual clearly says that it is for routing and nothing else. This is a natural behaviour for XHR, patched or not. Consider <base> tag.

Comment: @estus I cannot use the base tag. This is for a DotNetNuke module. I do not have control over the generation of the head tag. When you say it is natural behavior, what do you mean? XHR naturally appends the route path in a a parameterized route defined by Angular's routing module? Remember, the first path defined performs a GET against  the same mock API with the correct URL path.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'first router path', the question doesn't contain enough information about the behaviour you're having.  Any way, it is always as simple as using proper url for the request. You cannot expect that api/products/products.json will be prepended with APP_BASE_HREF, because it won't. Use absolute paths if you wish to specify url unambiguously, `APP_BASE_HREF + 'api/products/products.json'`. You can provide an interceptor for Http to do this automatically if you wish.

Comment: @estus Do you know where XHR gets the base URL from? Is it the current address in the URL bar?

Comment: @estus I have two routes defined, Both call the same API which is a constant. The first one works.The second one inserts `product` into the URL.

Comment: It is very likely either current address *OR* <base href...> url, I guess the thing you're describing confirms that. But I don't really remember the details since I always use absolute paths for the requests to avoid the mess with relative paths.